# Как импортировать DetailView из Django автонаводкой в Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: Здесь работает импорт]

Как можно сделать, чтобы работал импорт из Django?

[image: Здесь нету импорта]

Answer (score 0):

Решением является отметить venv-папку как excluded.